# ReflectionException PHP 8.1.2 Laravel 9.24.0 Function () does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-9

I've just started to use __invoke magic method in **Laravel 9**. Have been following the laravel 9 documentation and doing as what documentation suggests. I got this ***Function () does not exist*** error.

I have even created the *InvokeServer controller* using this artisan command

`php artisan make:controller InvokeServer --invokable`

> *The web route file below*

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\InvokeServer;

Route::get('/news',[InvokeServer::class]);
```

> *The InvokeServer Controller file attached below*

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class InvokeServer extends Controller
{ 
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }

}
```

After go through stackoverflow not having answer, I have changed this

```
Route::get('/news',[InvokeServer::class])
```

to as this

```
Route::get('/news',[InvokeServer::class,'__invoke']);
```

**It did work**, but that's not the way *__invoke* works. could anyone suggest a detailed explanation for this issue.

&

So My query here, *Is documentation syntax not working properly? or Am not using it properly if yes, How should I use it?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#single-action-controllers

Your route definition should be like this:

```php
Route::get('/news',InvokeServer::class)
```

No need for the array.

Answer (score 0):

Route::get('/news',InvokeServer::class)
сработало для меня, до этого юзал в массиве
Route::get('/news', **[** InvokeServer::class  **]**)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but read others' answers before giving an answer.Couldn't understand what you wrote.I think you give the same answer as above

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).